solana/web3.js Request Airdrop 429 error
I am trying to request an airdrop on the Solana testnet using the @solana/web3.js library in my Node.js application. However, I am encountering the following error:
Wallet balance is  0
Server responded with 429 Too Many Requests.  Retrying after 500ms delay...
Server responded with 429 Too Many Requests.  Retrying after 1000ms delay...
Server responded with 429 Too Many Requests.  Retrying after 2000ms delay...
Server responded with 429 Too Many Requests.  Retrying after 4000ms delay...
Error: 429 Too Many Requests:  {"jsonrpc":"2.0","error":{"code": 429, "message":"You have requested too many airdrops. Wait 24 hours for a refill."}, "id": "0b272aeb-e3e5-43c3-9b99-a1779bf8d382" } 
Wallet balance is  0

const {
  Connection,
  PublicKey,
  clusterApiUrl,
  Keypair,
  LAMPORTS_PER_SOL,
} = require("@solana/web3.js");

const wallet = new Keypair();
const publicKey = new PublicKey(wallet._keypair.publicKey);
const secretKey = wallet._keypair.secretKey;

console.log("public key:", publicKey);
console.log("secret key:", secretKey);

const getWalletBalance = async () => {
  try {
    const connection = new Connection(clusterApiUrl("devnet"), "confirmed");
    const walletBalance = await connection.getBalance(publicKey);
    console.log("Wallet balance is ", walletBalance);
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
  }
};

const airDropSol = async () => {
  try {
    const connection = new Connection(clusterApiUrl("devnet"), "confirmed");
    const fromAirDropSignature = await connection.requestAirdrop(
      publicKey,
      1e9
    );

    const latestBlockHash = await connection.getLatestBlockhash();
    await connection.confirmTransaction({
      signature: fromAirDropSignature,
      blockhash: latestBlockHash.blockhash,
      lastValidBlockHeight: latestBlockHash.lastValidBlockHeight,
    });
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
  }
};

const main = async () => {
  await getWalletBalance();
  await airDropSol();
  await getWalletBalance();
};

main();


Any ideas on why the airdrop isn't working?

You have hit the rate limit.
As the message suggests, you will have to wait till the 24 hours are up to request again.
More Info https://solana.com/docs/core/clusters#devnet
You might also want to check out https://faucet.solana.com/

I have this same problem. I have yet to get a single airdrop on devnet without using a VPN and going to the faucet with a never-before used wallet. There is zero chance that I've hit any rate limit. I've made like 10 requests for 1-2 SOL from this IP for as long as I've been alive.
Every time I Google it, I always end up with "you hit a rate limit."There is no way that that's  correct. Is it possible a ISP issue (using ATT fiber)?
